# Averaging 6 numbers that are outputted by a parsed JSON.

Tags: node-red

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to take the average number of 6 outputs (I believe these will be strings, so I think I'll need to convert them) coming out of a JSONpath node, which is parsing a JSON, resulting in the 6 outputs.

Here is my layout:

[image: Picture of my layout]

I'm not sure how to call the separate Sensor values that I'm parsing in the output, to be able to perform the average calculation.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I'm trying to use the "average" node, which claims to "Calculate the average of incoming msg.payload values from across a number of different msg.topic." However, it doesn't seem to be giving me an average.  It's still spitting out two separate numbers. in the description it says "Will return the current average of all different msg.topic values as msg.payload. Every other properties of incoming message will be pushed through." I'm having a tough time seeing how to separate the incoming parsed numbers into separate payloads, or topics.